# Adding rows of one DataFrame with same index

Tags: python-3.x, performance, pandas, dataframe

Here is a minimal example:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'x': [0, 0, np.NaN, 1], 'y': [1, 0, 0, np.NaN], 'z': [np.NaN, 1, 1, 0]}, dtype = int, index = ['a', 'a', 'b', 'b'])

       x      y      z
a      0      1    NaN
a      0      0      1
b    NaN      0      1
b      1    NaN      0
```

Values can only be 0, 1, or NaN. I want to add rows that have the same index, ignoring NaN values. The result would be here:

```
       x      y      z
a      0      1      1 
b      1      0      1
```

The way I am doing it:

```
df.max(level = 0)
```

Is there a faster way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is same, performace should be similar - mainly it depends of data:

```
df.groupby(level = 0).max()
```

Time comparison:

```
In [15]: %timeit df.groupby(level = 0).max()
    ...: 
100 loops, best of 3: 8.08 ms per loop
In [12]: %timeit df.max(level = 0)
    ...: 
100 loops, best of 3: 8.04 ms per loop
```

Some bigger data:

```
N = 100000
idx = np.random.randint(10000, size=N).astype(str)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.choice([0,1,np.nan], size=(N,3)), index=idx)
df = df.sort_index()
print (df.head())

In [174]: %timeit df.max(level = 0)
100 loops, best of 3: 19.5 ms per loop

In [175]: %timeit df.groupby(level = 0).max()
10 loops, best of 3: 24 ms per loop
```

Comment: @Arpit Solanki - Thank you for timings.

Comment: welcome. Deleted mine because does not make sense to give a slower solution

Comment: Thanks for the alternative and the timings @jezrael. Size of data is about `(20000, 200)`. I can see the timings between the two approaches are similar, as you mentioned.

Comment: @unfolx - You are welcome. Yes, exactly. I think `df.max(level = 0)` is less typing mainly, maybe `df.groupby(level = 0).max()` is more readable? Hard to say what is the best ;)